# What are Salvager Rank Certificates for?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

In Argentum, you can talk to certain nopon, so he can assess your "Salvager Rank". As for now, all I've found out is that once you advance in rank, you receive some useful items, but that's all. Are there any other uses for certificates?

Comment: I'm going to guess not, but I'll get more blades and do more quests before I definitively state that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a secret salvage shop in Indol behind a stack of crates on the dock you can only access with the appropriate Salvage Rank. There is more than one salvage shop don't confuse it with the one that is clearly visible.

Comment: Really? I was able to access that while on the lowest salvager rank... Unless you mean it gives you different options?

Comment: I don't remember the exact rank you need. If you talk to the npc without getting ranked it will say something like "sorry i only sell to salvagers with at least rank X". It is low probably the first or second rank.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, they don't do anything interesting or valuable besides indicate what your salvager rank is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are certain salvager shops that only deal with salvagers of a high enough ranking

Comment: Any proofs? I believe I have access to all locations aside of World Tree, and I have never encountered such.

Comment: There is one in Indol, somewhere behind some boxes in the docks area.